# MATLAB: Parsing text from a file, and converting to a mathematical set

Tags: parsing, matlab

A .txt starts each line with a variable length string I don't care about, followed by space-delimited ID's:

```
somegarbage 34532 2034 203 4 30403


garbage 2 45 2342 23 33503434
garbagethird 2
```

Lines 2 and 3 are empty.

All ID's on one line of the datafile should be

1. pushed into a mathematical set (i.e. {.} where order of the elements doesn't matter)
2. assigned to V[linenumber].

Example queries after read-in:

```
V[5]
  -> {2}
V[2]
  -> {}
```

What functions and data structures do I need?

If MATLAB does not have a ***set*** data structure, is there anything that's close, or will I have to resort to two-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you intend on doing with the data, this might be the approach:

```
V=importdata('A.txt')
V = 

      data: [2x6 double]
  textdata: {2x1 cell}
rowheaders: {2x1 cell}
```

V will be a struct with the field data which will contain all your "ID's". 
Then you can use `V.data(linenumber,:)` to get the row you want to mess with.

```
V.data(1,:)
ans =

   34532        2034         203           4       30403        3333
```

And rows can be of unequal length:

```
V.data(2,:)

ans =

       2          45        2342          23    33503434         NaN
```

Improved solution:

```
fid = fopen('A.txt');
tline = fgets(fid);
counter=1;
while ischar(tline)
v{counter} = strread(char(tline),'%s','delimiter',' ');
if ~isempty(v{counter})
    v{counter}=v{counter}(2:end);
else
    v{counter}={};
end
tline = fgets(fid);
V{counter}=cellfun(@str2double, v{counter}');
counter=counter+1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

This solution preserves empty lines:

```
V{1}

ans =

   34532        2034         203           4       30403

V{2}

ans =

 []
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this will only put all the ID's in one column, so that information on linenumbers is lost.

Comment: I stand by this solution, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, all id's are pushed into one column and I lose all information on which ID appeared on which line.

Comment: Just tested it again with a different data set (thanks for the edit). However, it ignores empty lines. I want empty lines to be included in the data AND I dont want the remaining indices to get messed up due to skipping empty lines. I changed my original post.

Comment: So now (most recent edit) I account for empty lines, as well as lines of varying length. I think that it should get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions that are well suited for this purpose: [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) and [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.htm). Both of them receive a format string that specifies the pattern of parameters in each line of the input text file.

#### Solution with `textread`:

`textread` requires the number of output variables to match the number of parameters read in each line, so you can do something along these lines:

```
[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6] = textread('myfile.txt', '%s %d %d %d %d');
V = [col2, col3, col4, col5, col6]
```

This yields:

```
V =
    34532        2034         203           4         30403
        2          45        2342          23      33503434
```

Essentially what you have is a *matrix* (*i.e.* an array of arrays), where each row corresponds to a line in the input text file. To access one of such rows, you simply do `V(row_index, :)`, for instance:

```
V(1, :) =
    34532        2034         203           4         30403
```

#### Solution with `textscan`:

`textscan` requires manually opening the file. It returns a cell array (which is actually a special type of an array that can hold multiple types of variables in the same set, such as strings with numbers). To obtain the same matrix as with `textread`, we use a comma-separated list and simple concatenation, like so:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %d %d %d %d %d')
V = [C{2:6}]
fclose(fid);
```

Now `V` should hold the same elements as in the first example.

If the number of parsed parameters is unknown, it is better to read the line as a whole string and parse it with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) instead:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');
V = C{1};
for i = 1:numel(V)
    V{i} = cellfun(@str2num, regexp(V{i}, '\d*', 'match'));
end
fclose(fid);
```

In this case the output `V` would be a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) (since a matrix requires the number of elements in each to be fixed). Each cell in the cell array would be an array of numbers (*i.e.* a vector), possibly of different length. For your example, the result would be a 3-by-1 cell array (ignoring the empty lines):

```
V = 
    [34532        2034         203           4       30403]
    [    2          45        2342          23    33503434]
    [    2]
```

Here you can access elements of each line using curly braces (`{}`), for example `V{2}`:

```
ans =
    [    2          45        2342          23    33503434]
```

A word of advice: format patterns and regular expressions greatly simplify string parsing, and are usually preferred in MATLAB over the straightforward method of iterating through the tokens using `for` loops. It also makes the solution more elegant, and much less cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work; however, there are too many integers on each line for me to manually set the columns. Sometimes there could be 0 id's on a line, other times there could be hundreds.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn So you have a variable amount of IDs. I have revised my answer.